# Unknown state error in moodle integration with keyclock using OpenId

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, moodle

I am getting below error in moodle integration with keycloak using OpenId

Unknown state.

More information about this error

Debug info:

Error code: errorauthunknownstate

Stack trace:

```
line 287 of /auth/oidc/classes/loginflow/authcode.php: moodle_exception thrown

line 133 of /auth/oidc/classes/loginflow/authcode.php: call to auth_oidc\loginflow\authcode->handleauthresponse()

line 168 of /auth/oidc/auth.php: call to auth_oidc\loginflow\authcode->handleredirect()

line 31 of /auth/oidc/index.php: call to auth_plugin_oidc->handleredirect()
```

Output buffer: Array ( [state] => rhcy8XXhwoOtCkZ [code] => 5b74206b-8bce-474f-bfbb-b82193a61c5a.80b7565c-17e5-4725-8204-c9e9cf826fcf.7474b906-61ec-4d54-a984-acf4672bcde3 [error_description] => )

I got this when am trying to solve this error.

In an authorisation flow, you have two steps. First you receive an auth code and then you use the auth code to obtain access tokens. When you receive a response at the redirect URL, there must be a way to verify that the response came for a request which you sent. The state value solves this issue by binding request and response. It is the client which should validate the response.

In my case 'state' is being saved in database in oidcclient.php. but from /auth/oidc/classes/loginflow/authcode.php file i am getting different value of 'state'.

What can be the issue. Can anyone help in this regard.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reaching out to the developers of that particular plugin and confirming whether they currently support integrations with keycloak. This is not a shipped plugin. The relevant 3rd party plugins page can be found here: https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_oidc

There is also a link on the page above to the github repo where issues can be reported and questions asked: https://github.com/Microsoft/o365-moodle/issues. Might be a good place to start.